# how to retrieve all the sns endpoints for a user?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

From an AWS Lambda function, I'm calling `client.create_platform_endpoint()` with a user's iOS device token.

Later I want to `publish()` push notifications for all the endpoints of a user. How can I retrieve all of a user's sns endpoints that have been created?

My approach is going to be a Dynamodb table mapping all the 'cognito_identity_id' values with all the `endpoint` values.

Is there a better approach I should consider?

Comment: I store them in a database.  Seems like that's what most people are doing.